# Power BI Between two Values

Tags: powerbi, histogram, dax, between

I've got a problem in PowerBI which im trying to solve for quite a while now.
I made a histogram which shows me how often a value exists.
For the values I have a upper and lower limit.
Also I want to have a vertical targetline which shows me where the values should be.
There's also a slicer where I can select different stations and depending on that the values, limits and targetgoal change.

[image: Histogram]

The problem is that the targetline doesn't always appear. Always then when there is no value at the exact spot where the targetline should be.

[image: Target Line not showing]

In this Picture the target line should be at 61. but there is no "Wert".

I really tried a lot of things to get it working but it just do not want to work. It only works if I set "show all values" on the shared axis. But I only want to see All_Values within the limits.

The DAX for the target line is: `targetline = IF(ISFILTERED(Stationen[Station]), IF( VALUES('Values'[All_Values]) =[Target],300,0),BLANK())`

So I hope there is a possibilitiy to only show "All_Values" in between the limits. I tried to write a measure but there are no measures allowed as shared axis.

```
Values_Between = CALCULATE(VALUES('Values'[All_Values]),Filter('Values'[All_Values]>[LL] && 'Values'[All_Values]<UL))
```

Because when I only show `All_Values` between the Limits, I can turn on "show values whith no data"

I would really appreciate if someone could help me. It can also be a completely different approach.